# PHP Clean CODE How to?

Tags: php

like my all teachers are saying " You can do everything because you can, but your code looks like a sh**"

So I was looking for some good tutorials on internet about Writing PHP code so clean as it's possible. I didn't find anything so I need your help.
I need some url with tutorials about how to write clean php code.
It can be BOOK as well!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: ^ Don't encourage OP to do the work for them.

Comment: surf well known projects on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your teacher what meant but I'm pretty sure writing clean code is write code what make sense.
What good write less if it's really hard to understand? For me, clean code doesn't mean syntax or less code only. Just write such that makes sense, use best practices and standards. It's a great start!
Because you brought up on books, here's one of these:

- [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)
- [The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master (old but great)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X)